# Conflict between two indirectly loaded shared libs on Linux, defining same symbols but, API incompatible

Tags: c, linux, linker, ld

### The Question:

Is it possible to avoid a conflict in C libraries name-space when 2+ libraries are *indirectly* loaded, that define the same symbols but are otherwise incompatible.

**Note:**

*Below I've listed library names, however the problem isn't specific to these libraries, it could happen with other libraries too. Only giving their names to avoid being unnecessarily vague.*

### The problem:

Using OpenGL and Python, its possible to get in the problematic situation of linking both `libreadline (gnu-readline)` via Python's `readline` module, and `libedit` via OpenGL -> LLVM.

The details aren't so important, (exactly how the libraries are indirectly linked), but the result is Python ends up using `libedit` when it expects `libreadline` and crashes, because they aren't 100% compatible (could go into details, suffice to say they use callbacks in a way Python doesn't expect).

Ideally LLVM would use `libedit` and Python would use `libreadline`.

### Possible workarounds:

So far I only came up with some weak solutions which only workaround the problem... and not really solving it (which is why I'm asking the question).

- statically link `libedit` to LLVM or `libreadline` to Python
  *(it could be done for a specific build, but for Linux distributions they typically want to dynamic link all libs)*
- force order-of-library loading by importing `readline` first. so Python's readline loads before OpenGL->LLVM->Libedit.
  *(maybe works in this case but potentially gives the reverse problem where LLVM expects `libedit` but gets `libreadline`)*.
- Create a fake `readline` Python module, which does nothing.
  *(Only works as long as you can implement or stub-out the parts of readline being used.)*
- Patch `libedit` to be compatible with `libreadline`
  *(Maybe best, but wont fix the problem short term)*

Comment: -fvisibility... not helping with such things?

Comment: @user2225104, not sure how `-fvisibility` applies, since both the libraries have to define the same API calls. The conflict isn't in my own code.

Comment: Maybe python under FreeBSD is linked against the non GPL libedit. Some kind of backporting might be the easiest way out, removing the dependency on readline altogether.

Comment: @user2225104, from checking Python's code, the exception is only of `__APPLE__`, But yes, using `libedit` is a possible solution if we used a patches Python, its just you don't always have complete control over the python installation of your users. If there is some way not to rebuild the libraries with special options, that would be preferable, especially since **we don't even use this library**, it just happens to load indirectly, we could also just stub it out... but would like to know if a cleaner solutions available.